# Swift - Get row index with checkbox in NSTableView

Tags: swift, cocoa, checkbox, nstableview

I'm learning Cocoa in Swift. I created a NSTableView with Viewbased.

[Simple tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Snp.png)

I also connected the checkbox action to ViewController. But when I clicked the checkbox, it printed -1 instead of the row index. I have to select the row first then click the checkbox to get the right index number. Are there anyway to get the row index with every single checkbox or button on each row? Here is my code:

import Cocoa

```
let data: [String] = ["Apple", "Microsoft", "IBM", "Tesla", "SpaceX", 
"Boeing" , "Nasa"]

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, 
NSTableViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.table.delegate = self
    self.table.dataSource = self
    self.table.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
@IBOutlet weak var table: NSTableView!


@IBAction func CheckClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    print(self.table.selectedRow)
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: 
NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    if (tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == "NameColumn"
    {
        if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: 
NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "NameColumn"), owner: self) 
as? NSTableCellView
        {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = data[row]
            return cell
        }
    }
    else if (tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == "CheckColumn"
    {
        if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: 
NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CheckColumn"), owner: self) 
as? NSButton
        {

            return cell
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    print(self.table.selectedRow)
}

}
```

Comment: The CheckClicked IBAction should go to the NSTableCellView subclass.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for, but a better implementation would be to use the action with a NSTableCellView subclass.

```
   @IBAction func CheckClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
        // print(self.table.selectedRow)

        let row = table.row(for: sender)
        print("Button row \(row)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I’m a newbie cocoa developer. I didn’t find any tutorial for advanced nstableview. Could you kindly show me how to make a subclass?

Comment: First you would create a new file -> Cocoa Class (Based on NSTableCellView). Second you assign the subclass to your table view cell in Interface Builder. Now you can setup IBOutlets / IBActions in the subclass to connect it to the controls in the table cell. It depends all what you are going to do if its useful to have the action in the cell view subclass or in the table view controller but in most cases you would assign an objectValue to the  table view cell and operate on it.

Comment: Well I did follow your guidance but stuck at control+drag outlet and action to the subclass file. Is this a Xcode's bug? I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 because this version allow me to connect to iTunes library framework without any issue.

Comment: If you open the new created subclass in the Assistant editor it should work with control drag. Be aware to select the right control in IB. In some cases its easier to select the control in the outline view on the left and to drag the connection (IBAction) from there.

Answer (score 0):

I can only create a subclass based on NSButton.

```
class myCustomView: NSButton{
    @IBOutlet weak var CheckButton: NSButtonCell!
}
```

Although I can't change the title of these button cell.

```
if (tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == "CheckColumn"
{
    if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier:
        NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CheckColumn"), owner: self)
        as? myCustomView
        {
            cell.CheckButton.title = data[row]
            return cell
        }
}
```

I don't know why Xcode doens't let me create a subclass based on NSTableCellView.